# How do I install filemagic in windows 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install

```
gem install ruby-filemagic

checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no                                         
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module                         
*** extconf.rb failed ***                                                          
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of                     
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more              
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

How can I fix this error on Windows 7?

Comment: What do you see when you follow the instructions to `Check the mkmf.lgo file for more detail`?

Comment: Here's a part of it

conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'magic_open'
c:/ruby193/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmagic

Answer (score 1):

```
checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no                 
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
```

First it checks if `magic_open` function exists in `magic` library, and it doesn't find it, which indicates you're missing magic library.

`libmagic` is not part of Windows, so you need to obtain or compile it on your own.

You can use the complementary DevKit that uses RubyInstaller to compile C projects, but you will need to get familiar with libmagic and GCC.

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby 1.9.3

Download [file-5.21.tar.gz](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/file-5.21.tar.gz) from ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/ and extract to a directory.

Download libgnurx 2.5.1 [bin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Other/UserContributed/regex/mingw-regex-2.5.1/mingw-libgnurx-2.5.1-bin.tar.gz/download) + [dev](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Other/UserContributed/regex/mingw-regex-2.5.1/mingw-libgnurx-2.5.1-dev.tar.gz/download) from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Other/UserContributed/regex/mingw-regex-2.5.1/) and extract both to another directory.

Run the DevKit msys shell

```
 c:\path\to\devkit-4.5.2\msys.bat -mintty
```

Build `file` from the directory you extracted it to.

```
 cd /the/path/to/extracted/file-5.21
 LDFLAGS=-L/the/path/to/libgnurx-2.5.1/lib
 CFLAGS=-I/the/path/to/libgnurx-2.5.1/include
 ./configure --prefix=/a/path/for/file-2.21
 make install
```

From inside the DevKit msys shell

```
 gem install ruby-filemagic -- --with-magic-dir=/a/path/for/file-2.21
```